# How to subtract multiple columns in R with condition

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like this. In my new dataset, I want to subtract the amount column(s) with principal column(s) and remainder(s) column.

For instance, if the `amount` column is 4, the `principal`column is 2 and `remainder` is 3, then the first amount column must be subtracted from the first principal column and first remainder column, 2nd with 2nd principal column and 2nd remainder column and 3rd with 3rd remainder column (since now there is no more principal column). And the last amount4 column must stay as it is as newamount4

```
amount1  amount2   amount3 amount4  principal1  principal2  remainder1  remainder2    remainder3  
 100      250       150    100           250       100         80         100          100 
 200      200       350    25            450       100        120         100          50
 300      150       450    30            200       100        150         100          100
 250      550       550    100           100       200         50         500          200
 550      200       650    200          250       200        500         100          500
```

My new dataset must look like this. Please note **am** stands for **amount** and **pr** stands for principal and **rem** stands for **remainder**.

```
 newamount1          newamount2         newamount3     newamount4       
 20(am1-pr1-rem1)    150(am2-pr2-rem2)  50(am3-rem3)   amount4        
 80                  100                300            amount4        
 150                 50                 350            amount4        
 200                 50                 350            amount4        
 50                  100                100            amount4
```

My code includes following script through which I am trying to get my desired output. My dataframe is named as **revised**

```
am_cols <- grep('amount_', names(revised)) 
rm_cols <- grep('principal_', names(revised)) 
sm_cols <- grep('remainder_', names(revised))

revised[is.na(revised)] <- 0


result <- cbind(revised[head(am_cols, rm_cols, length(sm_cols))] - revised[rm_cols] - revised[sm_cols], 
                revised[head(am_cols, length(rm_cols))] - revised[sm_cols], 
                revised[tail(am_cols, -length(rm_cols), -length(sm_cols))])
```

Comment: Very similar [How to substract multiple column based on condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026627/how-to-substract-multiple-column-based-on-condition-in-r)

Comment: @marc_s I reffered to above mentioned post but I am getting wrong output. There happens to be some error on my script where Head and tail function is not working properly.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Would you please edit you answer to include your code? Here is some [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask you question in a way that makes it easier for the community to help.

Comment: @xilliam I have edited my question and added my code which i am writing for desired output. I hope i have asked the question in the right way as i am new to SO.

Comment: @Ronak Shah could you please help me out with this?

Comment: could you also provide your data by running ```dput(revised)``` in the console, and copying that output into your question? (This is a typical way to provide sample data that exactly describes what you are working with.)

Comment: By my read, Arkun has provided what I think you are asking for. To make his code work with 'revised', just replace the 'df1' entries with 'revised', and run the code.  Does the solve your issue?

Comment: @xilliam I followed akrun solution and replaced df1 with revised. I also replaced 1:4 with '1:n' since i have more than 4 columns and it can be more than 100 or 200 as well. Although i am getting error which says {Error in 1:n : NA/NaN argument}

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split.default`

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(df1,
        sub("\\D+", "", names(df1))), function(x) Reduce(`-`, x))
df1[paste0('newamount', seq_along(lst1)] <- lst1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(amount1 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 250L, 550L), amount2 = c(250L, 
200L, 150L, 550L, 200L), amount3 = c(150L, 350L, 450L, 550L, 
650L), amount4 = c(100L, 25L, 30L, 100L, 200L), principal1 = c(250L, 
450L, 200L, 100L, 250L), principal2 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 
200L), remainder1 = c(80L, 120L, 150L, 50L, 500L), remainder2 = c(100L, 
100L, 100L, 500L, 100L), remainder3 = c(100L, 50L, 100L, 200L, 
500L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I followed your solution and replaced df1 with revised (which is my df name). I also replaced 1:4 with '1:n' since i have more than 4 columns and it can be more than 100 or 200 as well. Although i am getting error which says {Error in 1:n : NA/NaN argument}

Comment: what then is the value of 'n' in your code? Sounds like n may be an NA or NaN, as opposed to the number of amount columns.

Comment: @xilliam I replaced n with 100 assuming that I could have 100 amount columns. after I replaced n with 100 I am not getting the error {Error in 1:n : NA/NaN argument} But, After doing so i am still getting an error which says {Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames}.

Comment: Tricky to diagnose without more detail. I would suggest either clearing your global environment and re-run the code from scratch, or to add your full data object to the post with ```dput(revised)```. Strive for asking the question in a way that is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RahulMishra Can you try the updated code.   Are the column names of the same pattern as in the example showed?